# Map file contains entry only for the first instantiation of template function?

Tags: c++, templates, linker, map-files

Let's suppose I have the following template function in **a.h** file

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void foo(T arg)
{
   ...some code...
   std::cout<< arg <<std::endl;
}
```

And the following code in **a.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo<int>(5);
    foo<double>(5.25);
    foo<std::string>("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

When I look into **.map** file generated by linker (set /MAP (Generate Mapfile) option in VS) for this executable I see only one entry for foo function, which is

```
0001:000006f0       ??$foo@H@@YAXH@Z           004016f0 f i main.obj
```

However my assumption was that it should have contained 3 separate entries for foo function (one per instantiation). Viewing map file with Amap shows that this entry corresponds to

```
 void foo<int>(int)
```

function. Can someone please explain why there are no entries for

```
void foo<std::string>(std::string) 
void foo<double>(double)
```

functions?

Thank you

Comment: Did you actually *use* those instances. If not, the compiler would be well within its rights to optimize them out.

Comment: What do you mean by use ? As you can see in the code of a.cpp I call those functions.

Comment: The compiler might inline the function for some parameters. When I test with VS2017 (without "some code") they are all inlined.

Comment: Hi guys, looks like inlining was the case. Just looked into .cod files and found that functions were actually linlined. After using __declspec(noinline) I found entries for other instantiations too in the map file. It is strange that compiler inlines functions event when I use VS /Ob0(Disabled) option. I used it before posting this question, wasn't expecting that inlining can still be applied.